# Why aren't actions showing in WebApi Help Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi project in Visual Studio 2012. I created it from the template and have since added in the HelpPage stuff through the use of NuGet. Below is my example.

HierarchyController.cs

```
public class HierarchyController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public List<Hierarchy> Get([FromUri]List<Guid> guid)
    {...}

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Hierarchy> Children([FromUri]List<Guid> guid)
    {...}

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Hierarchy> Descendants([FromUri]List<Guid> guid)
    {...}

    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]List<Hierarchy> hierarchies)
    {...}

    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete([FromUri]List<Guid> guid)
    {...}
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{guid}"
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GuidApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{guid}",
            defaults: new { action = "DefaultAction", guid = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Result from .../help

> Hierarchy
>
> > API--------------------------Description
> >
> > GET api/Hierarchy-------Gets Hierarchy(s) by guid(s)
> >
> > POST api/Hierarchy-----No documentation available.
> >
> > DELETE api/Hierarchy--Deletes Hierarchy(s)

both of the "action" functions are missing from the help page. Any idea what I'm missing?

Also, everything does actually function correctly, the help page displaying everything is the only problem.

### Sub Question:

Also a secondary question I have defined xml comments for each of the functions such as

```
/// <summary>
/// Deletes Hierarchy(s)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="guid">List of Hierarchies</param>
/// <returns>HttpResponseMessage</returns>
```

They were all auto generated in VS2012 by typing `///` then just filling out the sections, but help page section for the Post always says "No documentation available." Is this because I haven't fixed the problem that shows up under the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` tab (Cannot use formmater 'JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter' error)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Regarding the 1st question:**
`List<Guid>` even though decorated with FromUri cannot be model bound as you might be expecting. This was a bug which was fixed recently and I think you are using the previous release bits and hence might not be able to see this. You can see what i mean by changing all the occurrences of `[FromUri]List<Guid> guid` with let's say `string guid`. You should now be seeing all the routes in help page. By the way, ApiExplorer explorers each route and for each route it explores all reachable controllers from that route. So, the results you would be seeing could be surprising, but are correct...just fyi.

**Regarding 2nd question:**
The documentation on actions is picked up from the documentation file that gets generated when you compile your project. You can enable it by doing: Project properties | Build | Output | check the 'Xml Documentation File'

Now uncomment the following line in the file 'Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs' and set the appropriate path to the documentation file location

```
//// Uncomment the following to use the documentation from XML documentation
//config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

Comment: 1st question - changing `List<Guid>` to `String` does make it appear on the help page. You mentioned it was a bug, is it a bug such that in the future `List<Guid>` would work, or is it a bug such that using `List<Guid>` should show an error/warning somewhere?

Comment: 2nd question - I already have the xml documentation stuff set to build, and the appropriate piece in HelpPageConfig.cs uncommented. The documentation shows for everything except the `POST api/Hierarchy` (sorry that wasn't clear in my question). Also, thanks so much for the help so far.

Comment: @jp36: In the future, `[FromUri]List<Guid>` would work. The list of values that you send from Uri would be properly bound and also helppage would show similar behavior as you are seeing with `string guid` here.

Comment: Thanks for the info, its very appreciated. I've marked this as the answer. Any insight into the sub question (with my added info from the 2nd question comment)?

Comment: @jp36: Regarding the 2nd question, do you mean you are not seeing the sample generation for the response of the `POST api/Hierarchy`? if Yes, this is expected behavior because HelpPage does not know the exact type of the action. In this scenaarios, you can use `SetActualResponseType` extension (you can take a look at an example of this in `Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs`) which allows you to set the actual response type.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was having trouble with this same issue even when using Web API version 2.2 and attribute routing.  It turns out that if you have a route parameter defined with the same name as the action parameter of type List<T> it needs to be optional or the action will not show up in the generated Help documentation.  I.E. `[Route("api/Hierarchy/{guid?}")]` or `[Route("api/Hierarchy")]` should be used so the action is displayed in the Help documentation.